# Postgresql Logical Replication is not working for some table

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I have setup logical replication between two servers in PostgreSQL 11. For some table replication is not working. I dropped those table from publication and added them back and refreshed subscription .still replication has not happened. I checked subscriber log ,no error there in the log also. what could be the reason for this . how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: replica identity ?

Answer (score 0):

ensure the parameters, Check the replication slot status and pg_subscription_rel status by refer the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-subscription-rel.html. If you could see status=i you have to re-configure the replication by increasing max_logical_replication_workers & max_work_processer.